# How to correct my 2D Outline Shader Graph in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, shader, sprite, outline

I am a very beginner in making shaders in unity and only follow steps in tutorials in channels and that cause several problem in process because tutorials is for older versions of unity for example I created a ShaderGraph -> URP -> sprite unlit Shader Graph instead of shader -> 2D renderer -> sprite unlit Graph, In short I made a shader Graph Outline for my 2D objects in scene but it's horrible and don't know how to correct it and some functions like "Volume -> Bloom" in camera component for making outline glowing doesn't work at all, I would be grateful if you could guide me.
[Outline Shader Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StRwb.jpg)

I changed outline Thickness and and redo with sprite lit shader Graph but doesn't work, my knowledge is shallow in shaders so I don't know what to do to make it correct, I hope some great guy come and show the way to me!